# Way to write http post request in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http-post

I am writing an app for hotel registration, where I am sending post request like below

`checkNetworkConnection` is just to check id there is active connection on device, if its true then I am calling `postFormData` method

```dart
Future<dynamic> checkNetworkConnection() async {
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup("www.google.com");
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        postFormData().then((val) {
          if (jsonDecode(val.body)[0]["response"] == "false") {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
              //isAbsorbing = false;
            });
            print(val.body);
            print("something went wrong");
            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
                title: Text("hello"),
                content: Text("something went wrong"),
              ),
            );
          } else if (jsonDecode(val.body)[0]["response"] == "true") {
            setState(() {
              isLoading = false;
              //isAbsorbing = false;
            });
            print(val.body);
            print("hotel added successfully");
            showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
                      title: Text("Hotel Added Successfully"),
                      content: Text("Hey there! Welcome to j1"),
                    ));
          }
        }).catchError((error) {
          setState(() {
            isLoading = false;
          });
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) {
                return new AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("error!"), content: Text(error.toString()));
              });
        });
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
                title: Text(
                  "Connection Error !",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.redAccent, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                content: Text("Check your internet connection !"),
              ));
    }
  }
```

`postFormData` method is like below

```dart
  Future<dynamic> postFormData() async {
      //there are declarations for parent and headers I just excluded them because they were quite a lot ^_^ !
      final response = await http
        .post("https://thej1.app/apiDataReq",
            body: parent, headers: httpHeaders)
        .then((val) => val)
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5))
        .catchError((_) {
      setState(() {
        isLoading = false;
      });
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) =>
              new AlertDialog(title: Text("error"), content: Text("error")));
    });
    return response;
  }
```

Is there any other of doing same ? Like with future builder?

My response body has a structure so that I can create response model. But I am unable to implement it in future builder.Also I want catch of exceptions and timeout errors.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to what you want help with? You want to use Future Builder instead of your current implementation? You want to catch errors? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: What do you think about my current implementation ? Is it fine? Or I really need to change this? If not, Can we do this with future builder?

Comment: So your code works but you want to know if there is a better way to do it? And you want to use a future builder?

Comment: Yes! My code is working fine , but I just want to know if there is any better way to do it , like future builder is an option , if there is any other please suggest